# How to iterate through excel sheets and unpivot dataframes. Then append them together into one daraframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unpivot, melt

I have Excel with 3 sheets: Gross, Margin, Revenue.
Each of them has a table with same columns and row headers.

I need to :

1) iterate through each sheet and save into a dataframe

2) unpivot each dataframe

3) append value columns from each daraframe into one.

**Gross:**

[image]

**Margin:**

[image]

**Revenue:**

[image]

**Outcome should be like this:**

[image]

If I use `sheet_name=None` then I get an error:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('BudgetData.xlsx', sheet_name=None,index=False)
df_unpv = df.melt(id_vars=['Company'], var_name ='Month', value_name = 'Gross Revenue')
print(df_unpv)
```

**Error I get:**

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-60-ee1791c449b1> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 df = pd.read_excel('BudgetData.xlsx', sheet_name=None,index=False)
----> 3 df_unpv = df.melt(id_vars=['Company'], var_name ='Month', value_name = 'Gross Revenue')
      4 df_unpv
      5 

AttributeError: 'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'melt'
```

**Excel file with sample data can be found here:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/9dsnylng70t5a8i/Count%20Open%20and%20Closed%20at%20Point%20of%20time.pbix?dl=0

Comment: First try concating the values of the ordered dict: `df = pd.concat(df.values(),sort=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call the `.melt()` method from your `df` object, instead of calling it from `pd` as the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) say:

`pandas.melt(frame, id_vars=None, value_vars=None, var_name=None, value_name='value', col_level=None)`

> Parameters:
>   frame : DataFrame id_vars : tuple, list, or ndarray,
>   optional Column(s) to use as identifier variables.
>
> value_vars : tuple, list, or ndarray, optional Column(s) to unpivot.
>   If not specified, uses all columns that are not set as id_vars.
>
> var_name : scalar Name to use for the ‘variable’ column. If None it
>   uses frame.columns.name or ‘variable’.
>
> value_name : scalar, default ‘value’ Name to use for the ‘value’
>   column.
>
> col_level : int or string, optional If columns are a MultiIndex then
>   use this level to melt.

Comment: Thanks, But it gives me an error. `'collections.OrderedDict' object has no attribute 'columns'`. @anky_91 solution works. I just need to understand how to append data